# Install over 20 triggers for multiple spreadsheets from a standalone central script

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I used to have one single script that installs 2 triggers for a few spreadsheets and now it turns out I need to do the same for 20-30 other spreadsheets as well. The issue here, which I just realized, is that google app script only allows you a maximum 20 triggers per one script.

Here is the scenario:
We want central control to all the spreadsheets in question and prevent the users from any means of accessing the scripts, which was why we used 1 standalone script for multiple spreadsheets. It is also easier to update.

However, now with the 20 trigger limit, the script can only run for 10 spreadsheet max, but I need at least double this amount. I am still new to the development environment in Google app script and what is a good solution to fit my needs here? Addons? Library?

Comment: Using an add-on is the best way to prevent users from seeing the script.  An add-on may be easier for users to install, but it's more difficult for the developer to publish.  But you can publish an add-on privately to avoid the need of getting approval from Google.  The add-on will run as if it were an independent project for each spreadsheet, using the quota of the user.  But an add-on can only install 1 trigger of each type per document.  For example, the add-on can't install 2 time based triggers for one Sheet.

Comment: You can install one time based trigger, and then have the code delete it, and install another time based trigger, but there can't be 2 active/existing time based triggers at the same time for one document used by the add-on.

Comment: The two triggers are on open and on edit, so I need the script to run when a user either access the spreadsheet or when he/she changes something. So I guess this is possible with the addon since they are different types of triggers, right?

Comment: Yes, the add-on can have both an "On Open" and "On Edit" trigger.